# AJAX request only happens once (PHP form request)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's roughly what I have for the main.php file.. A form, followed by where the data shows up and then the javascript:

```
<form>
    <center><h3>Add new person:</h3></center>
    <div class="errors"></div>
    <input id="nameOfFruit" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <select id="typeOfFruit" class="selectpicker"  data-width="100%">
        <option data-name="99">Select Fruit...</option>
        <option data-name="1">Tomato</option>
        <option data-name="2">Banana</option>
        <option data-name="3">Grape</option>
    </select>
    <select id="nOfFruit" class="selectpicker"  data-width="100%">
        <option data-name="99"># of Fruit...</option>
        <option data-name="1">1</option>
        <option data-name="2">2</option>
        <option data-name="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="addFruit">ADD</a>
</form>
```

This select-picker is the bootstrap add on Silvio Moreto's site.
Next I have some code where the tables for this data appear and are being read from the database. And finally, I have the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#wlFloorplans').selectpicker();
        $('#wlBedrooms').selectpicker();
    });

    jQuery('#addFruit').click(function () {

        var $opt = $("#typeOfFruit option:selected");
        var fruitString = $opt.attr("data-name");

        var str = "name=" + jQuery("#nameOfFruit").val()
            + "&type=" + fruitString
            + "&number=" + jQuery("#nOfFruit").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/adding_fruit.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function () { location.reload(true); });
                    $('#typeOfFruit').selectpicker();
                    $('#nOfFruit').selectpicker();
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(".errors").html(result.errors);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that everytime I fill out the form, one of two things happen:

a. The first time I fill it through, it will go through the ajax call and not put any data in the database. Then the next time I try, it will work.
b. The first time I try to fill out the form, it'll work (all the data enters the database, outputs on the table), but then the second time through, all the fields delete themselves when I press the add button and nothing gets placed into the DB.

Edit: my adding_fruit.php file:

```
<?php
try {
    //DB SETUP
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
}

$name = trim(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
$type = trim(isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '');
$number = trim(isset($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : '');

$errors = Array();
if (sizeof($_POST) > 0) {
    if ($name === '') {
        $errors[] = '<div class="alert" role="alert">NEED A NAME</div>';
    }
}

if (sizeof($errors) > 0 || sizeof($_POST) == 0) {
    $result = array(
        "errors" => implode("", $errors),
        "success" => 0);
    die(json_encode($result));
}

$randID = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

$sql = "INSERT INTO waitlist (id, name, type, number)
        VALUES ('".$randID."', '".$name."', '".$type."', '".$number."')";

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$result = array(
    "success" => 1);
die(json_encode($result));
?>
```

Do you see a problem with my code?

Comment: what should location.reload(true); expect to do??

Comment: Calling `location.reload()` is similar to clicking on the Refresh button, it reloads the page from scratch. That clears the form.

Comment: @Barmar the string gets passed into the php file "adding fruit" and that's where it gets placed in the database. then if successful, if goes to that if statement where it's refreshed.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef the string gets passed into the php file "adding fruit" and that's where it gets placed in the database. then if successful, if goes to that if statement where it's refreshed.

Comment: If it's not putting anything into the database, the problem is probably in `adding_fruit.php`. The code that sends the AJAX request looks OK.

Comment: @Barmar I added the extra file code... let me know if you see something wrong

Comment: You're using PDO, so you should use `bindParam()` instead of concatenating strings into the SQL.

Comment: You're setting `$email`, but you're storing `$number`.

Comment: No errors in console? My suspicision is the $(document).ajaxStop(function () { location.reload(true); }); messes things up. What are you trying to achieve with that line?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld after I add something, I want it to refresh the page so that I just added is showing

Comment: But why are you using ajax then? The whole  point of using ajax is to not reresh the browser?

Comment: this wall of code...is not approved.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld well the next step is adding that step. it's just that currently, I have a glitch and I can't figure it out. if I try to add into an option, it won't add, then retrying the same procedure again, adding to the same option it works. THEN if I try to add again to a different option, it doesn't work again the first time through.

Comment: @sharky do you know the problem here? I can't figure it out

Comment: I suggeste you learn howto do a normal form post first and then ajax. Not the other way around. ☺

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I will, but with the current code at hand, you see nothing wrong with it? I realized something is that it will only let me add once (first time) then it won't add anything, maybe something to do with manually clearing the form completely?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld the weirdest thing.. if I place the code above in a separate php file, and run this entire thing as a Modal form.. it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ajax you should not reload the entire page. That's the whole point using ajax (that you don't have to reload the page). What I think you are looking for is to clear the form (resetting to its original state) after user has submitted and the server responded.

**Try this:**

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/adding_fruit.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    $('form').trigger("reset"); //Reset to the original state of the form
                    $('#typeOfFruit').selectpicker();
                    $('#nOfFruit').selectpicker();
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(".errors").html(result.errors);
                }
            }
        });
```

The

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () { location.reload(true); });
```

is not needed, because `ajaxStop` is executed when ajax is finished undependently which ajax-call is made, not for a specific call like this. From the documentation:

> "Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are
>   any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers
>   the ajaxStop event."

and when `done()` is reached in your code then ajax is "finished" for your specfic call, so there's no need for `ajaxStop()` there. Therefore, if you want to reload the whole page after the call just do:

```
//This would reload the whole page 
//(just as you were hitting the reload-button in the browser)
location.reload(true);
```

**php:**

`die(json_encode($result));` says to end the application, but what you really want is to return the data:

```
echo json_encode($result);
return;
```